# Go to a different port from different domains

Tags: php, apache, subdomain

I have 2 "hypothetical" domains. myname.me, and myproduct.co.nz. I have four servers forded to the ports 44, 45, 80 and 90 of my public ip address.

The domains both have their A record set to my ip, so myname.me:44 and myproduct.co.nz:44 bring up the same page.

What I want, is for visitors to myname.me to see the page on the server operating on port 90, but not for them to see ":90" in the address bar.

I also want visitors to a.myproduct.co.nz to see the page on the server operating on port 44, and visitors to b.myproduct.co.nz to see the page on the server operating on port 45, both without seeing the :44 or :45 (e.g. I want the pages all serverd on 80).

The servers are all apache2 with php.

I guess that it would be something related to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html, but I am not sure how it would work with 2 servers.

I'd really appreciate any help.
~JJ56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup [name-virtual-hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) on your "port-80 machine". Then use ProxyPass (from [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)) within each virtual host definition, to pass requests from your "port-80 machine" to the other machines behind your firewall.

It might look something like the following:

(NOTE: The main server (your "port 80 server") has to be able to reach the other servers on your internal network -- I've used numeric addresses (192.168.1.5, and 192.168.1.6)).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myname.me/public_html
    ServerName myname.me

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.6/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.6/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproduct.co.nz/public_html
    ServerName myproduct.co.nz

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.5/
</VirtualHost>
```

Setup the virtual hosts *without* the proxy-related stuff first.  Make sure you can successfully resolve a test page in each of the two vhosts.  *then* (and only then) add in the proxy stuff, and start working the kinks out of that.

Answer (score 0):

While I want to answer your question, I have to ask *why* you would want to configure the server in this way. What it seems you're really trying to do is configure multiple domain (or `Name Based Virtual Hosts`) on this shared IP address.

If that's the case, then in Apache it's very easy to set up. Each domain will need to be defined in the httpd.conf or vhosts.conf (or inside of the catch-all include directory depending on your installation; see your documentation). A very basic set up would look like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywordpressblog.co.uk/public_html
    ServerName www.mywordpressblog.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You run one server on port 80 and use name-based vhosts, and you don't play any games with any other public ports. If you need different domains to hit different physical servers, you set up mod_proxy to proxy the requests to those servers, or you set up squid or varnish on port 80 to do the same thing. PHP doesn't come into it at all.